# Parameterize more than one border

Tags: cgal

If I parameterize a mesh which has more than one border as shown in the picture below, both border parameterization returns (0-1) texture coordinates, which I don't want. How do I parameterize it in such a way that both rectangles are side by side in texture after parameterization.

[Side by side rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvuhG.png)

If I parameterize all the borders will also lead to some problems since some of the borders may be inner holes of a polygon.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the parameterized 2d vertices before Normalized to 0-1. So that I can compute their 2d AABB and combine UV coordinate.

Comment: Is stitching the border of the mesh patches an option?

Comment: yes i can do that.

Comment: Can you give me some algorithm to stitching mesh patches, can we do it using CGAL?

Comment: You can use the function [`stitch_borders`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__repairing__grp.html) if you're mesh borders are compatible, otherwise you'll have to refine them to make them match if you want to use this approach.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking into stitch_borders.

Comment: I lose some normals if I stitch_borders, I have to find a way to find the parameterized vertices before Normalization.